# HTML/CSS to display members of a Social Community/Group

Tags: mysql, html, css

I am using MySql and PHP. I have a table groupXmembers that holds members of a group. I know a simple sql query will give me the members in resultset.

But I want to display these members in grid in my sidebar. I am looking for a copy-paste HTML CSS using which I can display users along with their pictures. I know how to display pictures. just want to know HTML and CSS.

Thank You
AJ

Comment: Why not select the TOP-5 from that recordset and then display all records? (Would never be more than 5.)

Comment: If you show us your website, maybe someone can came up with a sollution ..

Comment: Number of users to display does not matter. Displaying them is the issue here. HTML table or <divs> with CSS?

Comment: @yoda Its still not up. I am working locally right now. But side bar is a basic left side bar about 1.5 inches wide.

Comment: It's 1.5 inches wide? Only on your screen, I assume, since metrics and monitors aren't always compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically seen you want a list with users. So you should use a list (`<ul>`)

- Username
- Username

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="test.jpg" alt="test image" />Username</li>
  <li><img src="test.jpg" alt="test image" />Username</li>
</ul>
```